# Помогите правильно написать запрос на подвязку слов из перекрестной таблицы

Tags: sql, delphi

Помогите переделать правильно запрос,
Есть таблица `MAIN_TABLE` в которой в одном поле `id` строки, во втором содержатся слова, и конечно же в этом поле встречаются их синонимы. Чтоб я мог видеть слово и синонимы, я создал вторую таблицу `SYNONYM`, в которую вставляю слово и к нему соответствующий синоним, таким образом, к у одного слова может быть несколько синонимов.

При просмотре списка слов, я должен, каким-то образом подвязывать синонимы (из `SYNONYM`) к словам и выводить их в `TDBMemo`. Конечно я же в `DataSet` создал вычисляемое поле, в которое буду отображать синонимы.
Нужно написать что-то типа:

```
select mt.*, sy.* from MAIN_TABLE mt, SYNONYM sy where mt.ew1 = sy.ew1
```

но это не подходит, потому в результате я получу дублирование записей с одинаковыми `id` таблицы `MAIN_TABLE`, и всего лишь суммарно количество строк содержащихся не в `MAIN_TABLE`, а в `SYNONYM`

*Можно было создать просто строковое поле в «MAIN_TABLE» и не мучиться с таблицей «SYNONYM», но когда я хочу подвязать очередной синоним к слову, я открываю отдельный Query, где цветом показаны уже подвязанные слова (т.е. легче их найти)*

Comment: Что-то я не пойму, что нужно в итоге: список слов с синонимами, или список синонимов, или список слов с одним синонимом на каждое... приведите примеры содержимого таблиц и результирующие данные, которые Вы хотите получить...

Comment: В результате нужно получить все слова с «MAIN_TABLE», с привязанными к ним синонимами (список синонимов к каждому слову (если они существуют), должен выводится в TDBMemo)

Comment: Я лучше картинку сейчас нарисую

Comment: картинка - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rluabrm1cuzpapq/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. подробностей не приведено и если я правильно поняла вопрос, вот примерный запрос выводит все записи из первой таблицы и только связанные из второй:

```
SELECT mt.*, sy.* FROM MAIN_TABLE mt LEFT OUTER JOIN SYNONYM sy ON mt.ew1 = sy.ew1
```

Подробнее про объединение таблиц: http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html

Comment: **Спасибо** большое,   
и еще один вопрос, если можно:
**каким образом** в `dataset` избавиться от дублей `id`, они есть, если у слова несколько синонимов?